# How to add IConnectorClient to the botframeworkadapter

Tags: c#, botframework

We are trying to implement the scalebot sample solution. The OAuth Prompt in our dialogs do not work with the adapter we use. We get the following error

```
OAuthPrompt.Recognize(): not supported by the current adapter".
```

How to add the IConnectorClient to the botframeworkadapter?

Comment: Can you post some code on what you have tried so far?

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue?